# `by()` changed POSIXct to numeric value in R

Tags: r, numeric, posixct, posixlt

In R, how to prevent the `by()` function from changing POSIXct to numeric values automatically?

---

In the following example, the `time` object is class  `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"`. When using `by()` function, the output is `numeric`. But when doing what `by()` does manually, e.g. `min(time[index=='a'])`, the output is still `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"`, which is desired. Is there a way to prevent the `by()` function from changing POSIXct to numeric values automatically?

```
time = c("0001-03-04 05:36:00 UTC", "0001-03-04 05:50:00 UTC", "0001-03-04 06:05:00 UTC")
time = as.POSIXct(time, tz = "UTC")
index = c("a", "a", "b")

by(time, index, min) # results are numeric values.
min(time[index=='a']) # "0001-03-04 05:36:00 UTC"
```

Comment: another solution is using `data.table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Return a list and then concatenate the elements of the result.

```
do.call("c", by(time, index, function(x) list(min(x))))
##                         a                         b 
## "0001-03-04 05:36:00 UTC" "0001-03-04 06:05:00 UTC"
```

**2)** split/lapply would also work:

```
do.call("c", lapply(split(time, index), min))
##                         a                         b 
## "0001-03-04 05:36:00 UTC" "0001-03-04 06:05:00 UTC"
```

**3)** as would tapply with simplify = FALSE:

```
do.call("c", tapply(time, index, min, simplify = FALSE))
##                         a                         b 
## "0001-03-04 05:36:00 UTC" "0001-03-04 06:05:00 UTC"
```

**4)** aggregate can be used.

```
with(aggregate(time ~., data.frame(time, index), min), setNames(time, index))
##                         a                         b 
## "0001-03-04 05:36:00 UTC" "0001-03-04 06:05:00 UTC"
```

or if names are not needed:

```
aggregate(time, list(index), min)$x
## [1] "0001-03-04 05:36:00 UTC" "0001-03-04 06:05:00 UTC"
```

or to get a data frame result:

```
aggregate(time ~., data.frame(time, index), min)
##   index                time
## 1     a 0001-03-04 05:36:00
## 2     b 0001-03-04 06:05:00
```